# How to Solve Reindexing Issue for Large Catalog in Magento

Tags: magento

I have approx 70000 products in my catalog.Whenever I do some changes on product level,it takes lot of time to update the change.

Answer (score 0):

Check & follow these steps

- To clear all the locks for re-indexing locate var/locks directory and remove all files under this directory.
- Now, login to your MysQSL/phpMyAdmin to run the following MySQL query (Ensure that your have taken full backup before committing this MySQL query):

> DELETE cpop.* FROM catalog_product_option_price AS cpop    INNER
>   JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo    ON cpo.option_id =
>   cpop.option_id    WHERE    cpo.type = 'checkbox' OR    cpo.type =
>   'radio' OR    cpo.type = 'drop_down';

and

> DELETE cpotp.* FROM catalog_product_option_type_price AS cpotp
>   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS cpotv    ON
>   cpotv.option_type_id = cpotp.option_type_id    INNER JOIN
>   catalog_product_option AS cpo    ON cpotv.option_id = cpo.option_id
>   WHERE    cpo.type <> 'checkbox' AND    cpo.type <> 'radio' AND
>   cpo.type <> 'drop_down'

- Log back in to your Magento Admin panel and go to System tab > Index Management hit index again and you will notice no such errors will appear again. You can follow these same steps again if re-indexing stops in future to resolve Magento ReIndexing issues.

Comment: @Magento_ocodewire--I am not getting any type of error when performing reindexing.My problem is product save is taking too much time.Solution provided by #Ankur Goyal works well

Answer (score -1):

Use three step in magento database (mysql) and Solve Re-indexing Problem

First step:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `index_process_event`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `index_event`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `index_process`;
```

Second step:

```
CREATE TABLE `index_event` (
`event_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`entity` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`entity_pk` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`old_data` MEDIUMTEXT,
`new_data` MEDIUMTEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_EVENT` (`type`,`entity`,`entity_pk`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `index_process` (
`process_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`indexer_code` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`status` ENUM('pending','working','require_reindex') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
`started_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`ended_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`mode` ENUM('real_time','manual') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'real_time',
PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_CODE` (`indexer_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Third  step:

```
INSERT INTO `index_process`(`process_id`,`indexer_code`,`status`,`started_at`,`ended_at`,`mode`) VALUES (1,'catalog_product_attribute','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(2,'catalog_product_price','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(3,'catalog_url','pending','2010-02-13 19:12:15','2010-02-13 19:12:15','real_time'),(4,'catalog_product_flat','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(5,'catalog_category_flat','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(6,'catalog_category_product','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(7,'catalogsearch_fulltext','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(8,'cataloginventory_stock','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time');

CREATE TABLE `index_process_event` (
`process_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`event_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`status` ENUM('new','working','done','error') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`,`event_id`),
KEY `FK_INDEX_EVNT_PROCESS` (`event_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_EVNT_PROCESS` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `index_event` (`event_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT` FOREIGN KEY (`process_id`) REFERENCES `index_process` (`process_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How do the steps in your answer make the indexing process faster?